# Cant open tilestache url in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tilestache

I was trying to install tilestache on Ubuntu server by following these [steps](https://gist.github.com/tomay/8657441). After finishing step 12, I tried to run tilestache-server.py and open serverip:8080/osm/preview.html with my browser  but the web page is unavailable. When I run `curl -IL "127.0.0.1:8080/osm/preview.html"` in the server terminal, it gave me response like this :

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1137
Server: Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.6
Date: Wed, 12 Aug 2015 08:48:05 GMT
```

It seems like it run locally but can't be accessed from the internet. Opening http://serverip gave me a fine result of apache default page. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Werkzeug runs it's own server, adding *"logging": "debug"* to your tilestache.cfg should show you eventual problems in the logs on command line.

I found [this guide](http://proyectosbeta.net/2015/05/tilestache-en-ubuntu-14-10-desktop/) really easy for an initial TileStache setup on Ubuntu.